# How do I use NLTK's default tokenizer to get spans instead of strings?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

NLTK's default tokenizer, nltk.word_tokenizer, chains two tokenizers, a sentence tokenizer and then a word tokenizer that operates on sentences. It does a pretty good job out of the box.

```
>>> nltk.word_tokenize("(Dr. Edwards is my friend.)")
['(', 'Dr.', 'Edwards', 'is', 'my', 'friend', '.', ')']
```

I'd like to use this same algorithm except to have it return tuples of offsets into the original string instead of string tokens.

By offset I mean 2-ples that can serve as indexes into the original string. For example here I'd have

```
>>> s = "(Dr. Edwards is my friend.)"
>>> s.token_spans()
[(0,1), (1,4), (5,12), (13,15), (16,18), (19,25), (25,26), (26,27)]
```

because s[0:1] is "(", s[1:4] is "Dr." and so forth.

Is there a single NLTK call that does this, or do I have to write my own offset arithmetic?

Comment: What you mean by "offset". Maybe string index on list? i.e: 'Dr.' is index 1..

Comment: Edited to clarify what I mean by offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least since NLTK 3.4 [TreebankWordTokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/treebank.html) supports `span_tokenize`:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer as twt
>>> list(twt().span_tokenize('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'))
[(0, 4),
 (5, 7),
 (8, 11),
 (12, 20),
 (21, 23),
 (24, 26),
 (27, 34),
 (35, 42),
 (43, 44)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, most Tokenizers in nltk have a method called `span_tokenize` but unfortunately the Tokenizer you are using doesn't.

By default the `word_tokenize` function [uses a TreebankWordTokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html). The `TreebankWordTokenizer` implementation has a fairly robust [implementation](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/treebank.html) but currently it lacks an implementation for one important method, `span_tokenize`.

I see no implementation of `span_tokenize` for a `TreebankWordTokenizer` so I believe you will need to implement your own. Subclassing [TokenizerI](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/api.html) can make this process a little less complex.

You might find the `span_tokenize` method of `PunktWordTokenizer` useful as a [starting point](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html).

I hope this info helps.

Comment: I whipped up a three-second version of a  here: https://gist.github.com/ckoppelman/c93e4192d9f189fba590e095258f8f33.  Any help or advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`pytokenizations` have a useful function `get_original_spans` to get the spans:

```py
# $ pip install pytokenizations
import tokenizations
text = "(Dr. Edwards is my friend.)"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tokenizations.get_original_spans(tokens, text)
>>> [(0,1), (1,4), (5,12), (13,15), (16,18), (19,25), (25,26), (26,27)]
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/tamuhey/tokenizations#get_original_spans) for other useful functions.

Comment: This function is deprecated (get_original_spans)

Answer (score 0):

NLTK version 3.5 's [TreebankWordDetokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/treebank.html) supports the function `span_tokenize()` so there is no need to write an own offset arithmetic anymore:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
>>> s = '''Good muffins cost $3.88\\nin New (York).  Please (buy) me\\ntwo of them.\\n(Thanks).'''
>>> expected = [(0, 4), (5, 12), (13, 17), (18, 19), (19, 23),
... (24, 26), (27, 30), (31, 32), (32, 36), (36, 37), (37, 38),
... (40, 46), (47, 48), (48, 51), (51, 52), (53, 55), (56, 59),
... (60, 62), (63, 68), (69, 70), (70, 76), (76, 77), (77, 78)]
>>> list(TreebankWordTokenizer().span_tokenize(s)) == expected
True
>>> expected = ['Good', 'muffins', 'cost', '$', '3.88', 'in',
... 'New', '(', 'York', ')', '.', 'Please', '(', 'buy', ')',
... 'me', 'two', 'of', 'them.', '(', 'Thanks', ')', '.']
>>> [s[start:end] for start, end in TreebankWordTokenizer().span_tokenize(s)] == expected
True
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before answering an already answered question (green check-mark) it's best to check whether your answer duplicates any of the existing answers. Your answer here seems to duplicate the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55787917/5698098) from Fibo Kowalsky. Duplication is rarely something good; and may be seen as unwanted distraction on Stack Overflow (on which you may get down-votes). See also [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works.