# get indices of original text from nltk word_tokenize

Tags: python, text, nltk, tokenize

I am tokenizing a text using nltk.word_tokenize and I would like to also get the index in the original raw text to the first character of every token, i.e.

```
import nltk
x = 'hello world'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
>>> ['hello', 'world']
```

How can I also get the array `[0, 7]` corresponding to the raw indices of the tokens?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are looking for is the `span_tokenize()` method.
[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678318/how-do-i-use-nltks-default-tokenizer-to-get-spans-instead-of-strings) this is not supported by the default tokenizer.
Here is a code example with another tokenizer.

```
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer
s = "Good muffins cost $3.88\nin New York."
span_generator = WhitespaceTokenizer().span_tokenize(s)
spans = [span for span in span_generator]
print(spans)
```

Which gives:

```
[(0, 4), (5, 12), (13, 17), (18, 23), (24, 26), (27, 30), (31, 36)]
```

just getting the offsets:

```
offsets = [span[0] for span in spans]
[0, 5, 13, 18, 24, 27, 31]
```

For further information (on the different tokenizers available) see the tokenize api [docs](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/api.html)

Comment: I added a span_tokenizer to the TreebankWordTokenizer here: https://gist.github.com/ckoppelman/c93e4192d9f189fba590e095258f8f33. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

You can also do this:

```
def spans(txt):
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(txt)
    offset = 0
    for token in tokens:
        offset = txt.find(token, offset)
        yield token, offset, offset+len(token)
        offset += len(token)


s = "And now for something completely different and."
for token in spans(s):
    print token
    assert token[0]==s[token[1]:token[2]]
```

And get:

```
('And', 0, 3)
('now', 4, 7)
('for', 8, 11)
('something', 12, 21)
('completely', 22, 32)
('different', 33, 42)
('.', 42, 43)
```

Comment: That won't work. word_tokenize function may replace token's text for something else - for example, " (double quote) for `` (two backticks). So your call txt.find(token, offset) returns -1.

Comment: replace `nltk.word_tokenize(txt)` with the customized function `word_tokenize(txt)`. It should work. `def word_tokenize(tokens):
    return [token.replace("''", '"').replace("``", '"') for token in nltk.word_tokenize(tokens)]` (sorry, I don't know how to change line in comments.)

Answer (score 0):

`pytokenizations` have a useful function `get_original_spans` to get the spans:

```py
# $ pip install pytokenizations
import tokenizations
tokens = ["hello", "world"]
text = "Hello world"
tokenizations.get_original_spans(tokens, text)
>>> [(0,5), (6,11)]
```

This function can handle noisy texts:

```py
tokens = ["a", "bc"]
original_text = "å\n \tBC"
tokenizations.get_original_spans(tokens, original_text)
>>> [(0,1), (4,6)]
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/tamuhey/tokenizations#get_original_spans) for other useful functions.