# How to compute accuracy of NER system?

Tags: python, classification, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I am using several NER tools in order to extract the Named Entities present in a corpus and I want to test their accuracy using the NLTK Python module.

Some of the tools I have used are:

- NTLK
- Stanford NER: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml
- MeaningCloud: https://www.meaningcloud.com/products/topics-extraction

In order to obtain the system's accuracy, NLTK's `accuracy` function takes two arguments: the correctly annotated dataset (containing all the tokens in the corpus along with their classification (PERSON, LOCATION, ORGANIZATION or 'O' [which represents that the token is not a Named Entity]) and the output of the NER system.

This is ok when the NER returns a list of all the tokens with their classification. However, some tools, such as MeaningCloud only return the classification for the named entities recognized in the corpus. This makes the accuracy impossible to obtain (in order to obtain it, the full list of words should be returned for the comparison between both annotations to be doable).

What is the approach here then? What could I do in order to obtain the accuracy in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a list of tags for all tokens where the default is 'O'.

Looking at MeaningCloud, it looks like `variant_list` includes the locations in the original string where the token was detected, so you can use that to map labels to tokens.

Some pseudocode:

```
def get_label(token, meaningcloud_data):
    variants = ...[get from meaningcloud_data somehow]...
    for variant in variant:
        if token.start_char >= variant.inip and token.end_char <= variant.endp:
            return variant.label
    return False

meaningcloud = get_meaningcloud_data(text)
labels = []
for token in tokens: 
    # default to 'O'
    labels.push(get_label(token, meaningcloud) or 'O')
```

Note that in NLTK the standard tokenizer - `word_tokenize` - doesn't save token positions, so you can't reconstruct the original document unless you're absolutely sure of the spacing conventions. That said NLTK does have means of tokenizing and getting positions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668493/get-indices-of-original-text-from-nltk-word-tokenize) for some details.