# How to find the index of named entity in stanford nlp

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using python wrapper for stanford nlp
The code to find named entity is:

```
sentence = "Mr. Jhon was noted to have a cyst at his visit back in 2011."
result = nlp.ner(sentence)

for ne in result:
  if ne[1] == 'PERSON':
     print(ne)
```

the output is result which is a list type:
   (u'Jhon', u'PERSON')

but it doesn't give the index of named entity like in spaCy or other nlp tool it gives result with index.

```
>> namefinder = NameFinder.getNameFinder("spaCy")
>> entities = namefinder.find(sentences)
List(List((PERSON,0,13), (DURATION,15,27), (DATE,76,83)),
  List((PERSON,4,10),  (LOCATION,77,86), (ORGANIZATION,26,39)),
  List((PERSON,0,13), (DURATION,16,28), (ORGANIZATION,52,80)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `nltk` for this. I adapted the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668493/get-indices-of-original-text-from-nltk-word-tokenize). The key point is to invoke the use [WordPunctTokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) and the method `span_tokenize()` to generate a separate list that I call `spans` that keeps the span of each token.

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer

# Initialize Stanford NLP with the path to the model and the NER .jar
st = StanfordNERTagger(r"C:\stanford-corenlp\stanford-ner\classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz",
       r"C:\stanford-corenlp\stanford-ner\stanford-ner.jar",
       encoding='utf-8')

sentence = "Mr. Jhon was noted to have a cyst at his visit back in 2011."

tokens = WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(sentence)

# We have to compute the token spans in a separate list
# Notice that span_tokenize(sentence) returns a generator 
spans = list(WordPunctTokenizer().span_tokenize(sentence))

# enumerate will help us keep track of the token index in the token lists 
for i, ner in enumerate(st.tag(tokens)):
    if ner[1] == "PERSON":
        print spans[i], ner
```