# Internal implementation of nltk pos tagger

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

i am new to NLP and trying to use nltk pos tagger, and got a doubt on usage,

It usually accepts a word or a complete sentence, and gives pos tag of the input, why it is working in both way ?

i got this doubt because, i tried removing stop words and used spacy pos tagging technique and my colleague said i shouldn't do in that way because results change as it checks for positioning of words also,

Will it be same for nltk pos tagger also? if yes then why it accepts single words since positioning is considered?

sample usage found here for both use cases in nltk: https://github.com/acrosson/nlp/blob/master/subject_extraction/subject_extraction.py#L61

https://github.com/acrosson/nlp/blob/master/subject_extraction/subject_extraction.py#L44

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sentence of one word is still a sentence, so from a software engineering point of view, I would expect a tagger module to work the same regardless of the length of the sentence. From a linguistic point of view, that's not the case.

The word `positioning` is what seems to be confusing you. Many PoS taggers are based on sequence models, such as [HMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) or [CRFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field)`*`. These use context feature, e.g. what are the previous/next words in the sentence. I think that's what your colleague meant. If you only consider the previous one word as context, then it doesn't matter how long the sentence is. The first word in any sentence has no previous word, so the tagger has to learn to deal with that. However, adding context can change the decision of the tagger- let's look at an example using `nltk`

```
In [4]: import nltk

In [5]: nltk.pos_tag(['fly'])
Out[5]: [('fly', 'NN')]

In [6]: nltk.pos_tag(['I', 'fly'])
Out[6]: [('I', 'PRP'), ('fly', 'VBP')]

In [7]: nltk.pos_tag(['Large', 'fly'])
Out[7]: [('Large', 'JJ'), ('fly', 'NN')]
```

As you can see, changing the first word affects the tagger's output for the second word. As a consequence, you should *not* be removing stopwords before feeding your text into a PoS tagger.

`*` Although that's not always true. NLTK 3.3's PoS tagger is an averaged perceptron, and spacy 2.0 uses a neural model- the argument about context still holds though.

Answer (score 0):

The `nltk.pos_tag()` function takes a **list of tokens** as input. This list can contain an arbitrary number of tokens, including, of course, 1. There is more info in the [API documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html).

So in the first example you cite, `nltk.pos_tag([w])`, `w` is supposedly a single word string and `[w]` places it into a list, as required by the function.

In the second case, `nltk.pos_tag(sent)`, the `sent` variable in the list comprehension is a sentence that has already been tokenised into a list of tokens (see line 41 in the code you cite - `sentences = tokenize_sentences(document)`), which is also the format required by `pos_tag()`.

I'm not sure why your colleague advised against using spaCy. It depends on what you want to do. Contrary to NLTK, spaCy stores a rich set of features on each token, including the token's index (position) in the document and character offset in the original text. As far as I know, NLTK does not store token index and character offsets by default, so you would have to try and retrieve this yourself (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668493/get-indices-of-original-text-from-nltk-word-tokenize) perhaps).

Comment: its not against spacy, it is about not removing stop words and then using spacy, forgive me if it conveyed in other way

Comment: No problem. I misunderstood, but I think mbatchkarov's answer maybe answers your question then.

Comment: but i cannot appreciate that, since i don't have enough karma